# SSRS - How to autorefresh to the next page multiple pages report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, report, rdl

I have a SSRS report that has 4 pages. I want it to refresh to the next page every x seconds. When it reaches last page, then report should loop back to the first page.

I have sql server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:
i have created an html file with refresh to the next page that is not ideal but does the job.

Solution 2:
Also, i have found reference that creating 3 sub reports will work by hiding them according to parameter value.

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>1</title>
            <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="120;url=C:\html\2.html"/>
            <meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="0" />
            <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">


            </HEAD>
            <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
            <!--
            * { overflow: hidden; }
            -->
            </STYLE>
            <body scroll="no">

            <iframe style="overflow:auto" height=100% width=100% scrolling=no src="" > 


            </iframe>

            </BODY>
            </HTML>
```